# Woocommerce permalink URL change in DB

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, database, wpdb, wp-redirect

I am changinf URL structure and product URL on the wwebsite.
Problem is this:
When I change permalink structure on the WordPress admin, it creates directly new URL with new structure for each product.
Example:
*domain.com/eshop/wine/spanish/spanish-wine-2022* => *domain.com/spanish-wine-2022*

And after I need to redirect *domain.com/spanish-wine-2022* => *domain.com/spanish-wine*

Ting is once I will make last redirect, there wil lstill exist URL that Wordpress created (*domain.com/spanish-wine-2022*) and it will be accessible. Can i somehow from DB remove all these  URLs that WP created?